# Get seed of URL in crawler4j visit()

Tags: java, url, web-crawler, crawler4j

Hi how do I get the seed where it came from of the page in crawler4j's visit function?
So far i have the url of the page but i cant figure out what was the seed that lead to there.

```
public void visit(Page page) {

    String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
}
```

Comment: noone knows or is the question stupid?

Answer (score 0):

```
page.getWebURL().getParentUrl();
```

Comment: This only gets parent url one generation up. If it's a depth of more than 1, this won't help you to get the original seed.

Comment: If you store the parent urls of all crawled pages, you can generate parent-child url tree and find original seed.